# How manage when several annotations has similar or the same coordinates and want to show them?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I have an app (iPhone) that uses MapKit and users can create things on the map (annotations in the remote database, with latitude and longitude).
Problem is that very often users put things in the same building, very close, even in the same coordinates. So you only see the most up-to-date annotation unless you tap it and another is shown, but the usability of this is horrible. No users realize they can do that.

Therefore I guess a way to group close points and when tap, show all of them. It seems the first step can be done with clusters and I see several libraries for iOS for that:
http://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20cluster

I would like to know if you have any idea or suggestion to solve the second problem, or the whole problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the clustering library used, you may be able to get the clustered region that is represented. Then, upon cluster marker tap, you could zoom to that region.

The JS library Leaflet has this behavior so you can see what it's like:

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-zoomtobounds.html

I realize this is a JS library not ObjC, but just linking it for demo purposes.